# Open form with combobox item selected

Tags: excel, vba

I’m loading a 2 column table into a 2 column combobox, column 2 is the bound column.  I want to have the form open with a combobox item already selected.  I’m having success with Macro1, but in Macro2 the line `.cmb1.Value = 4` raises an error.    I’m not sure why that is, could someone give me an explanation?

[image]

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim f As myFrm
    Set f = New myFrm
    With f
        .cmb1.RowSource = [myLst].Address
        .cmb1.Value = 4 'displays Wed in combo
    End With

    f.Show

End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    Dim f As myFrm, v
    Set f = New myFrm
    With f
        .cmb1.List = [myLst].Value
        .cmb1.Value = 4 'Error
    End With

    f.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Here's the relevant part of Excel VBA 2010 help:

> For a ComboBox, changing the contents of Value does not change the
>   value of BoundColumn.

Not that you need it, but here's an alternative:

```
With f.cmb1
    .List = [myLst].Value
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .List(i, 1) = 4 Then
            .ListIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't know why the help is, apparently, wrong for `RowSource`. I seldom use `RowSource`, as it's so limiting.

Comment: I meant to say regarding wrong in a situation where the list was created with `RowSource`.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms my experience.  I normally stay away from `RowSource` too, but as I stumbled onto this "loophole" re Value, I'll probably make an exception in this case.